# Best Practice for handling duplicate INSERT statements

Tags: java, sql, database, sql-server-2008, exception

I am currently using Java to try to INSERT a customer in my Database:

```
public void saveCustomer(Customer c)  {
    getConnection();

 try {

     CallableStatement pstmt =  con.prepareCall("{call sp_saveCustomer(?,?)}");
     pstmt.setString(1, c.getName());
     pstmt.setString(2, a.getLastName());
     pstmt.executeUpdate();

     closeConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

When a user tries to INSERT a duplicate record, the catch block will trigger. What I'm worried about is that I don't know if this means a performance hit. Isn't a better way to check if a customer already exists? Something like:

```
public void saveCustomer(Customer c) {
    getConnection();

 boolean exists = false; 


     CallableStatement pstmt =  con.prepareCall("{call sp_checkCustomerExistence(?,?)}");
     pstmt.setString(1, c.getName());
     pstmt.setString(2, a.getLastName());
     ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
     if (rs.next()) exists = true;
     if ( exists ){
     closeConnection(); 
     return;
     } 

     CallableStatement pstmt =  con.prepareCall("{call sp_saveCustomer(?,?)}");
     pstmt.setString(1, c.getName());
     pstmt.setString(2, a.getLastName());
     pstmt.executeUpdate();

     closeConnection();

}
```

What would be the best solution based on the best performance? Should I check myself if the customer exists or should I let the Exception be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think checking the duplicate is preferable than catching the exceptions.** Only suggestion I have it to perform the check in your procedure itself if you can i.e. create a procedure as `sp_check_and_save_customer` which will check for duplicate and save if it doesn't already exist. This way there will be very less time difference between the check and insert, which becomes more crucial in heavy loaded applications.

**Still, please have your exception handling as well** as it is still possible that another process inserts the data in between the check and insert.

Answer (score 1):

Checking before hand = two database calls or two IO interactions. Attempting to just insert with the possibility of an exception occurring exception is only one. As long as the exceptions are handled, they aren't necessarily a bad thing.

Although probably not preferred, it would be the fastest of the two methods you've listed.

Answer (score 1):

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
```

The `SQLException` that you are catching could mean anything. It doesn't necessarily mean that it occured because of a duplicate row in the database table. So, simply it is not reliable enough to be used for that use-case.

You just have to make a call before trying to create one, to handle it in a proper manner.